# Steam Application not displaying big window when I click on it

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, gaming, steam, application-launch

[image: Steam Application not displaying big window when I click on it.]I'm having trouble with my Steam app every time I click on the app it doesn't display but when I hover over the icon it displays a sneak peek of the app.

Comment: Select your program so it is active (practise on a program you can see) then press Alt + Enter, then either M or S and move/size with the arrow keys. If off screen attempting to move will bring it on screen. Press Right/Down arrow keys if it has a zero size.

Comment: @Mark didn't work. :(

Comment: After selecting it by clicking on the preview image, try holding down the windows key and pressing the up arrow a few times. If that doesn't work, hold down windows and shift, then pressing the left arrow key

Comment: Also. double-clicking the steam icon in your taskbar (by the clock) might help.